# How to get the auto generated ID of a Firestore document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use the auto generated ID when I create my document.
After setting, I need to get it.

```
await admin.firestore().collection("mycollection").doc().set(mydata)  
    .then(doc => {

        console.log(doc.id);

        return true;
     })
     .catch(err => {
         return false;
     });
```

The retrieved ID in the log is not the same as the ID in the Firestore Database. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The retrieved ID in the log is not the same as the ID in the Firestore
>   Database.

This is normal, since the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method returns a `Promise<void>` (i.e. a Promise which resolves to an `undefined`). Therefore you cannot do `doc.id` in the callback function passed to the `then()` method, since `doc` is `undefined`.

You should do as follows:

```
try {
  const docRef = admin.firestore().collection("mycollection").doc();
  const docId = docRef.id;  //Here you have the value of the id (independently of the fact you call set() later or not)

  await docRef.set(mydata);
} catch(err) {
  //...
}
```